# cpanel - how to track a disappearing htaccess file

Tags: cpanel

I have a wordpress site where permalinks keep breaking--only on my live instance.  I have a local and a dev instance with the same code/plugins, settings, etc.

I have several different suspicions as to what's happening, but only tracking the file will give any of those suspicions validity.

I'm using hostgator and am trying to set this up with their support, but they're not being very helpful.

Would anyone have any suggestions as to where to start?

Answer (score 0):

Can it be that their system automatically deletes a file, in case it feels it is Suspicious?

It seems to be something like that. Cpanel doesn't delete the .htaccess by itself nor any other file inside your public_html dir.